# regex pattern to match end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex string to match just after the end of the first string (doesn't have a trailing slash or white space)

```
https://domain/a/ab
https://domain/a/cd/
```

This is so that I can append a parameter onto the end of it, so something like this:

https://domain/a/ab**&letters=true**

So far, I've come up with this, but it just matches on the last character of the string, which isn't what I want

```
(?!https:\/\/domain\/.*?)(.)$
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match ? What tool/language are you using ?

Comment: language - js - I want to match the end of the first string

Comment: "the end" ? Seriously... You have to be a little more precise if you want to play with regexes

Comment: what you need to do is to match first to last character of the string you want preppended using a capturing group and then outside of the matching, append the additional text to the captured group. (The appending part is done outside of the regex)

Comment: Wouldn't appending anything to the string always append it to the end anyway? What's the point of using regex for it?

Comment: The end of the string meaning to match just after the last character. The append isn't important in this case, I'll have another think about the capturing group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append that text to the original string, this would do :

```js
var string = "https://domain/a/ab\nhttps://domain/a/cd/";
string = string.replace(/^(.*)(\n.*)/, "$1&letters=true\n$2");
console.log(string);
```

Comment: I also came up with this - which also achieves the same outcome (might be of use to someone) - (?<=https:\/\/domain\/a\/ab.*)$

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I'm going to make some asumptions:

- You have a multiline string containing urls.
- You want to append querystring parameters to each one of them, based on the routes

---

#### Regex to capture the last character of each line

So far, you've tried to use a regex to match the last character of each line, I don't think this will help you accomplish what you're looking for. In any case when having multiline strings you might use the [flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) `g` and `m`.
From mozilla:

> `g`:global match; find all matches rather than stopping after the first match
>
> `m`: multiline; treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple lines (i.e., match the beginning or end of each line (delimited by \n or \r), not only the very beginning or end of the whole input string)

With these flags an expression as simple as [`/(.)$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/2bkzgv/1/) captures the last character of each line.

---

#### Regex to capture each url

Based on the assumptions I made, I think you'd be better off capturing the urls and mapping them:

[`/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+(\/?.*)$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/1KBJaj/1)
This regex matches a url per line, and captures the path after the domain.

You mentioned you were using javascript so here's a demo:

```js
const regex = /^https?:\/\/[^\/]+(\/?.*)$/gm;
const str = `https://domain/a/ab
https://domain/a/cd/
https://domain/
http://domain
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```